# Error: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'study_type_question_group_id' for Study.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error while running my application:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'study_type_question_group_id' for Study.):
app/controllers/protocols_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

I have gone through through some online solution but not able to solve the problem. Column 'id' is available in my 'study_type_question_group' table.

```
My controller code : ( a fraction of my full code)
--------------------------------------------------
 def create

unless from_portal?
  @service_request = ServiceRequest.find session[:service_request_id]
end

@current_step = cookies['current_step']

new_protocol_attrs = params[:study] || params[:project] || Hash.new
@protocol = self.model_class.new(new_protocol_attrs.merge
                                    (study_type_question_group_id: StudyTypeQuestionGroup.active.pluck(:id).first))

@protocol.validate_nct = true

if @current_step == 'cancel'
  @current_step = 'return_to_service_request'
elsif @current_step == 'go_back'
  @current_step = 'protocol'
  @protocol.populate_for_edit
elsif @current_step == 'protocol' and @protocol.group_valid? :protocol
  @current_step = 'user_details'
  @protocol.populate_for_edit
elsif @current_step == 'user_details' and @protocol.valid?
  @protocol.save
  @current_step = 'return_to_service_request'
  flash[:notice] = "New #{@protocol.type.downcase} created"

  if @service_request
    @service_request.update_attribute(:protocol_id, @protocol.id) unless @service_request.protocol.present?
    @service_request.update_attribute(:status, 'draft')
    @service_request.sub_service_requests.each do |ssr|
      ssr.update_attribute(:status, 'draft')
    end
  end

  @current_step = 'return_to_service_request'
  flash[:notice] = "New #{@protocol.type.downcase} created"
else
  @protocol.populate_for_edit
end

cookies['current_step'] = @current_step

if @current_step != 'return_to_service_request'
  resolve_layout
end
```

end

I have many files in my project, if you want to look on them you can look at here: https://github.com/ctsiteam/cnmc-sparc-request

Answer (score 0):

So I have added attr_accessor:study_type_question_group_id in my Model. And now it's working.

It seems like there were some problems with access because i have used attr_accessible earlier but now I have both.